# php string date to datetime format

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert string date time to datetime format. bellow is my code

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore");

$EventDate = '2018-09-14 16:30:00.000';

$createDate = new DateTime($EventDate);
$NewEventDate = $createDate->format('Y-m-d h:m:s');
```

but when i convert string date to datetime, i get time wrong bellow is the output

```
STRING EVENT DATE : 2018-09-14 16:30:00.000
CONVERTED EVENT DATE : 2018-09-14 04:09:00
```

the time 16:30:00 shows 04:09:00 which is wrong

Comment: Use `H` instead of `h`

Comment: Why are you bothering to do all this just to get EXACTLY the same format out as you put in?

Comment: i tried that also but returns 2018-09-14 16:09:00 the minuets is wrong

Comment: `i` is minutes, no?

Comment: Also use `i` instead of `m`

Comment: Please just read the [documentation in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for all the fomatting characters. It will save you and us a lot of time

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for the characters that you need to use. @RiggsFolly You are to fast ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$NewEventDate = $createDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: You missed the `H` not `h` error

Comment: @RiggsFolly , thank you for pointing, i updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use i instead of m for minute

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore");

$EventDate = '2018-09-14 16:30:00.000';

$createDate = new DateTime($EventDate);
$NewEventDate = $createDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore");

$EventDate = '2018-09-14 16:30:00.000';

$createDate = new DateTime($EventDate);
echo $NewEventDate = $createDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```